# dealing with files and streams via OpenCL (GPU)

Tags: opencl, gpu

I want to write in a file from the kernel of OpenCL .. something like fwrite() in C ..

Are there any function like that .. or what I have to do to write in a file from GPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. It is not only the synchronization issue with hundreds of threads, the kernel is running on special devices like GPU or accelerator cards. These cards do not have access disks and other IO.

Data can only send and received from memory and the CPU can do the complex IO.

In general: A GPU (OpenCL device) can only get data from memory and do something with it locally. After the signal arrives at the CPU that the OpenCL kernel is finished, the data is fetched from the GPU The GPU is a pure slave without any control about its environment.

Comment: I get Convinced with your answer but I have a question.
what if GPU processor wants to write an image or a 3-D model, what should he do?

Comment: The GPU can't do that. The kernel finishes the calculation and stores the result in global memory. The host CPU reads the memory and writes everything to disk or whereever it needs to be placed.

Comment: Ok, Can this be done with parallel processors with CPUs .. In other words, Can OpenCL with CPU deals with files?

Comment: No, the OpenCL specification does not support this and the OpenCL code is compiled by a special OpenCL compiler.

Comment: please, kindly read this question .. :)
In parallel processing, how to make each processor execute a block of program using mathematica

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not available. How would you handle 1000 threads writing to the same file in a safe manner? That would slow down the computations enormously. Printf is there for debugging only.

So you need to send the information to the host and let the host handle the correct writing to the file. The best method to send the data back, depends on your kernel/algorithm.

Comment: I took the 1000 threads issue into account .. I mean that every single thread write in separated file .. Is that possible?